# How to write at specific position in a fixed lenfth string or char buffer

Tags: java

I need to create fixed length records which consist mostly of space but which are sparsely populated at certain known positons. Essentially what I need to produce is a legacy file format in which the records consist of a large number of fixed length fields. I only need to populate a handful of these fields so I want to create the empty buffer full of spaces first, and write formatted fields of specifc length at specific positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();// Or use StringBufer if you need synchronization
b.append("----------"); //use dash instead of space for visibility
int pos = 4; 

String replacement = "foo";
b.replace(pos, pos + replacement.length(), replacement); //Attention: if the length of the replacement is greater than the length of the original content, the exceeding chars will be appended
System.out.println(b); //----foo---
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I took a quick look at the StringBuilder docs but missed the replace method. I added a check for the string length to make sure I don't accidently expand the buffer:
  if (string.length() > length) throw new   IllegalArgumentException("Length of input string > field length.");

Answer (score 2):

Consider the use of StringUtils for leftPad, rightPad, center and repeat. http://www.jdocs.com/lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

As you are creating the result by your self, this would help, so you don't really need to handle positions and substrings...

Comment: This would be useful for formatting each field but as the record will be sparsely populated I dont want to produce a blank field for each of the 100 or so fields in the records, or have to update code to produce the blank strings in between the used fields every time I add a new one. I this case simplicity is more important than efficiency so I have gone for Thomas's approach.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't start by creating a String of spaces, whose length is the total length of the record.  I would just use the `StringBuilder` class and append fields as needed (it grows automatically when it needs to).  I would append spaces to each field when adding the field to the record.

```
public class FixedWidthBuilder {
  private StringBuilder record = new StringBuilder();

  public void append(int len, String value){
    if (len < value.length()){
      value = value.substring(0, len);
    } else if (len > value.length()){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
      for (int i = value.length(); i < len; i++){
        sb.append(' ');
      }
      value = sb.toString();
    }
    record.append(value);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return record.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a class that represents your fixed length record and which knows about each field in the record.  Default to all spaces and provide setters for the fields you care about.

Internally, the implementation is up to you.  Perhaps a combination of the answers from Thomas and user1001027 seems reasonable.